# Como dirigirse a una section desde otra pagina

Tags: php, laravel

```
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <div class="mr-auto"></div>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link smooth-link" href="#hero">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smooth-link" href="#features">Fechas</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smooth-link" href="#blog">Noticias</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smooth-link" href="#project">Música</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <a href="#contact" class="btn smooth-link align-middle btn-primary">Contacto</a>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>`
```

Buenas estoy desarrollando una pagina web con una plantilla de boostrap 4 y laravel en mi index tengo distintas section con un nav las cuales al seleccionar el foco se centra en donde estan esas section, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer si estoy en otra pagina html y ir directamente a section contacto por ejemplo la cual esta en el index , no se si se entiende

Comment: Tienes que ponerle un id fijo a tus secciones. ¿Puedes hacer eso con la plantilla?

Comment: Eso ya lo tengo , mi pregunta es si se puede hacer desde otra pagina

Comment: Ok. Entonces debería ser sencillo, a los enlaces de la otra página solo tendrías que añadirle `#` más el id de la sección a la que quieres hacer deep linking.

Comment: tambien ya lo hice si me funciona de la misma pagina al seleccionar un componente por ejemplo blog de mi nav me lleva hacia abajo donde esta la section blog , si apreto contacto me lleva a la section contacto que esta al final de la pagina y asi con los demas elementos, pero cree un elemento del nav que es fotos donde al seleccionar se abrira otra pagina php donde estara la galeria ahi se visualizara la misma nav que esta en un .blade pero si selecciono contacto no hara nada , porque ya no esta en el index

Comment: entonces como podria hacerlo si estoy en otra pagina php al seleccionar se valla al index y a la section elegida , se puedo , o creo que no

Comment: No sé cómo creas el enlace, pero si es a la página de index, el enlace se debería ver algo como `/index#seccionid`

Answer (score 0):

1.- Establece un id en la section contacto (creo que ya lo tienes por lo que puedo comprender).

2.- En el enlace del menu debes añadir al final el id con la "#". De esa manera puedes navegar en el DOM hacia el id dentro del enlace establecido.

Saludos!

Comment: si ya lo he hecho asi arriba tengo el nav y desde las section con el id funciona  <section class="padding bg-grey" id="contact"> todo bien eso pero lo que yo quiero hacer es en otra pagina php por ejemplo videos seleccionar desde ahi el enlace de contacto y que me lleve al index y a la section donde esta no se si se entiende :c

Comment: Puedes crear el enlace de forma dinámica con PHP (si estoy entendiendo bien tu problema con eso lo solucionarías) de tal forma que para cara nueva generación dinámica de página este enlace esté ahí (en el lugar donde lo establezcas). No trabajo en Laravel pero imagino que ese menú está almacenado en una tabla de tu Base de Datos, por lo que desde cualquier página que sea mientras esté consultando a la misma base de datos podrás realizar la consulta a la misma solicitando el enlace. No sé si estoy entendiendo bien tu problema (espero que si).

Comment: la solucion era hacerlo de esta manera esta desde otra pagina php <li><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>

Comment: Pero al implementarlo con laravel no se como hacerlo porque da errores

Answer (score 0):

A que se refiere la documentación de [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) puedes hacerlo de maneras diferente

> Route vea https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

tienes que definir la ruta de la pagina y el parámetro para la sección
la solución puede variar en caso que utilizas algún Marco progresivo de JavaScript. como **VueJS** o otro similar. 
en este caso puedes acceder desde tu navegador utilizando la ruta `http://localhost/#miseccion` para que tengas una idea.

En cualquier caso deja ver tu código para que todos tengamos una idea mas clara
en esta

Comment: Esta respuesta es realmente muy mala.

Answer (score -1):

Gracias a los que respondieron , lo he solucionado de esta forma:

```
href="{{route('inicio')}}#videos">Videos</a>
```